# Font of Netbeans in Ubuntu 10.04 is very ugly

Tags: netbeans, ubuntu, fonts

I have installed oracle java jdk 6 update 30 . Then I installed Netbeans 7.1.
But Netbeans's font is very ugly.But eclipse works without any problem

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660515/how-to-fix-netbeanss-look-on-ubunbu

Comment: It can't fix my problem.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/32624/ugly-fonts-in-netbeans-how-can-i-make-it-use-the-system-font

Answer (score 1):

old topic , but if you add this in  `netbeans.conf` 
( `netbeans.conf` at `netbeans installed directory/etc/netbeans.conf`  )

add this line to the end of file :

`netbeans_default_options="-J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on --laf com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel"`

after that , reset netbeans , font will look better !

if font still too ugly , you can use `font forge` app to clear  anti aliasing  of your font , i my case , i have to remove anti aliasing  of monospaced font , after that , netbeans font look perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

If you feel that the current font is ugly, you can change it.

> Tools --> Options -> Fonts & Color

Here you can choose a lot of parameters maybe it will help you having a better render.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic but for future visits, here is a solution that works:

```
# Install both infinality and fontfix'ed JDK.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:no1wantdthisname/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:no1wantdthisname/openjdk-fontfix
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fontconfig-infinality openjdk-7-jdk
# Apply a font style that looks good.
sudo /etc/fonts/infinality/infctl.sh setstyle linux
# And reboot the system.
sudo reboot
```